# Newbie: How to make .pl file executable?

Tags: perl

I don't know anything about PERL first of all. I know very limited html. My assignment is to upload a .pl file (provided to me) to my cg-bin dir on my web server, then make the file executable. I had to manually create a cgi-bin dir into my public_html dir. I uploaded the .pl file. How do I make it executable?

Comment: Don't forget to set the right permissions on the directories too (`chmod a+x ~ ~/public_html ~/public_html/cgi-bin`)

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod a+rx /path/to/your/file.pl
```

You may want to check out the `chmod` man page as well. Just type

```
man chmod
```

in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Manually creating the `cgi-bin` directory probably isn't going to work. The web server needs to be configured to recognise the directory as well. And we can't help you with that as we don't know which web server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you will need to `chmod`

Also (depending on webserver, which you haven't tolYou need to put the path to your Perl executable in the first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/perl
```

This will be particular to your server though - you'll need to ask your admin or teacher what it should be for you.